# JQuery Mobile not working in Eclipse Blackberry project

Tags: javascript, css, eclipse, blackberry, jquery-mobile

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

This code works as expected in IE. However when I drop the exact code into my Blackberry project in Eclipse the JQuery does not seem to pick up. The css and js files are local int he root directory of the eclipse project. I've searched the internet, but have found nothing related to this. Any ideas?

Comment: What Blackberry OS/device are you testing on? is it supported? http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: I'm using the blackberry simulator for now. Torch 9800.

Comment: On the simulator can you navigate to www.google.com ? are you running the files locally? debug console errors/warnings?

Comment: would seem there is no internet access on the simulator. I pulled the files locally and updated the above code to show they are pointed locally. No errors, the program runs, just without JQuery, I just get basic HTML.

Comment: Do you have a config.xml file with a <content> element telling WebWorks which page (e.g. index.html) to load?

Answer (score 0):

Did your LogCat turned on? I'm getting same problem with you (but in Android apps). LogCat says : `SyntaxError: parse error at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js:3195`.

I just comment line 3195 on that file, and the jQuery Mobile styles shows up